# Waiting for Javascript with HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I was experimenting with HtmlUnit the other day. I wrote a program that performs a login to a site and gathers some information. But when clicking a specific button, htmlUnit doesn't wait for the resulting action. I tried to wait till all jobs from the JavascriptJobManager are done but it gets stuck at around 15 jobs. After that I tried to wait till the resulting htmlpage changes, but that does not work either. What could I try next ? Thanks for your time and I will try to implement any suggestion as fast as possible.

Edit: I´m completely aware that facebook doesn't like webcrawling, but I´m only doing this for study purposes, so no harm done. Following the error messages, the program throws. http://www.pastebin.ca/3007578

When the infoButton gets clicked, a new window appears making the old window unaccessible. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGQLV.jpg

```
final static WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_31); 
public static void main(String [] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException{
    //init webclient
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(12000);
    webClient.setAlertHandler(new AlertHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleAlert(Page arg0, String arg1) {
            System.out.println("ALERT ON "+arg0.getUrl()+"  :"+ arg1);
        }
    });

    // perform the login
    final HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("https://facebook.com"); 
    final HtmlForm form = loginPage.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("email");
    final HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("pass");
    final HtmlElement button = (HtmlElement) loginPage.getElementById("u_0_l");
    username.setText("Your email");
    password.setText("Your password");
    final HtmlPage frontPage = (HtmlPage) button.click();

    // The actual problem
    final HtmlPage testPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stackoverflow/1462865420609264");
    HtmlElement infoButton = testPage.getFirstByXPath("//*[@class='share_action_link']"); // First share button.

    HtmlPage testPage2 = infoButton.click();

    JavaScriptJobManager manager = testPage2.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
    while (manager.getJobCount() > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100);
        System.out.println(manager.getEarliestJob());
    }

    while(testPage == testPage2){
        System.out.println("failed");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(100);
        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are disabling throwing JavaScript exception, you should enable that to see why it fails. Also please use v 2.16, and provide your URL and button so others can check

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for the response. I edited the post to have a minimal working example. Furthermore I linked the exceptions and errors which the program produces. Unfortunately I do not understand, how to fix those.

Answer (score 1):

With [latest snapshot](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_QuickBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts) (in maven also), there was an error that window.performance is not defined, which was fixed.

**EDIT:** there was another error detected, fixed and snapshot deployed.

Please retest

Comment: Hey Ahmed,
thanks for the quick help, but unfortunately updating to 2.17 didnt solve the problem. The program still throws the same exceptions and errors. The button I want to access should be globaly available within Facebook. I added a picture briefly explaining the wanted result.

Comment: So far, logging for me works with clicking on element "u_0_n", and there is an exception but that needs debugging local copy of JS and comparing with real browsers, as hinted in http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html

Comment: Hi, did you try again, after 10 may?

Comment: Oh I did not notice that you wrote again. With the new snapshot my program is Exception free, with some errors. (Updated the pastebin link with the new error log). Sadly it still does not work as wanted.

Comment: There is no error for me (possibly a location/advertisement difference). The only thing I changed is loginPage.getElementById("u_0_n"); Anyhow, the error of duplicate i parameter is valid, as there is function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,i,k), you can remove it by http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse

Comment: I would like to work on the problem first before solving all warnings, any advice how I could guarantee, that the Javascript opens the "share functionality window" (See picture for reference). I tried to save both the "before" and the "after" Page to my Harddrive and open it with a real browser, but that didn't work at all. Thanks for the help so far.